# how do i reach apache on a vitualbox machine

Tags: apache, windows-7, lamp, virtualbox

I am trying to run a virtual LAMP machine on my windows 7 for dev purposes. But i cant figure out how to reach the apache from the host windows 7 system. I did an ifconfig and tried the ipaddress, but to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set virtualbox to use bridged (regular) networking then it's no different from any other machine on the LAN, if you set host only then you can still call it - you just need to know it's IP address.

See http://opensourceexperiments.wordpress.com/2008/04/18/virtualbox-case-study-making-host-only-networking-work-between-two-ubuntu-guest-os-virtual-machine-on-windows-vista-host/

Answer (score 1):

You will need to set the networking mode of your VM in virtualbox.

- **Bridged** will allow others on the LAN
  to access your VM.
- **Host-Only** will allow your host and
  any other VM's also configured as
  host-only to access one another.

Comment: Another option is to keep the networking mode on NAT, but to do port forwarding as described in the VirtualBox user manual.

Answer (score 0):

[Virtual Box Neworking](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#id2531041)

If you look at the link you will have many different options on the type of networking you can do.

as mentioned earlier, I recommend either:

Bridged

networking that makes the box look like an other computer on your network. They you may use ipconfig on the box or verify your router logs.

Host-Only

networking is where your windows 7 will be its own network between the box and windows and then you may use the Ip address from ipconfig.